# Pass ant properties file in jenkins ant build setup

Tags: ant, jenkins

I am trying to find out the way in which the ant prorperty file can be passed in  "Invoke Ant" build steps. Can you please show me the right direction.

As per the jenkins "Invoke Ant" description,  it can only accept name1=value1.

Please suggest me!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can put your ant property file to your project, and use build.xml to include your property file, something like this:

build.xml:

```
<property file="build.properties"/>
```

project structure:

```
your_project
--build.xml
--build.properties
```

Comment: Thanks  Zhaozhiming. I am aware of this but i am prop fly created on the fly so have to include via jenkins only.